# Jump in another section of another file

Tags: html

If I am viewing an `index.html` file, how can I navigate directly to a specific `<p>` of `index-2.html`?

In `index.html`, I've tried adding this:

```
<a href="#here-i-want-to-jump"></a>
```

And in index-2.html:

```
<p id="here-i-want-to-jump">Ciao sono un testo qualunque</p>
```

But it's clear that the id doesn't exist in index.html. How can I perform this navigation?

Answer (score 2):

You should include the reference to index-2.html:

```
<a href="./index-2.html#here-i-want-to-jump">Some text</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$<a href=" index-2.html#here-i-want-to-jump">Redirect to section of second Page</a>
```

Its Easy You can Try this

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is create an *anchor* in the second page and navigate to it from the first. The important thing is that the paragraph you want to "jump" to is the one that needs the ID, not the link in the first page.

So in `index.html` you'd have a link like this:

```
<a href="index2.html#here-i-want-to-jump">Click to jump!</a>
```

And in `index-2.html` you'd have the id set on your target:

```
<p id="here-i-want-to-jump">I should land here after the jump!</p>
```

Note that if your `index-2.html` page is not very long, or if the target is close to the bottom, it might not seem like the jump worked because your browser window is too big (or your content is too small).